# i want random number

Tags: solidity, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

Looks like keccak256 () isn't working or not How could I correct it?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/niguezrandomityengine/ethereumAPI/nreAPI.sol";

contract Randomness is usingNRE {

   function randomNumber() public view returns (uint256){

       return (uint256(keccak256((rw()/(10**20))%(10**12))));
   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `keccak256` should give you a random number??? It would give the exact same result on every execution! BTW, there's an undefined symbol in your code - `rw` - which you need to explain.

Comment: I don't think keccak () will give me random numbers. But I do not understand why it is an error. And how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the error??? Please don't just dump code here and ask others to run it and understand what your problems are. Explain what youv'e tried, how you've tried it, what errors you've encountered, how you've tried to tackle each one of them, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since solidity 0.5 `keccak256` is expecting `bytes` as input and you are passing an `uint`.

You can use [`abi.encodePacked`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/miscellaneous.html#global-variables) to convert an arbitrary input to bytes.

```
keccak256(abi.encodePacked( (rw() / (10**20) ) % (10**12) ) )
```